# How to replace blank cells in data with excel or r?

Tags: r, excel

I have a data file I want to read into 'R' from excel but it contains blank cells and I would like to replace the blank cells with a word. I have searched online but I am yet to get a tutorial that can solve this problem. Can anyone advise me on how to replace blank cells in the data with either Excel or 'r'?

Answer (score 1):

See `gsub` function. For example:

```
gsub(pattern =" ",replacement = "X", x = c("a b", "e    d"))
```

removes the spaces by "X"

Comment: Thanks, David Cros the example you shared works but I when I add my data it does not; for example if I do this gsub(pattern =" ",replacement = "X", x = my_data) it does not. What do you think is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: how does your `my_data` object look like ? is it a vector ? a dataframe ? do you get an error message ?

Comment: It is a data frame and it does not show an error message when I run the function the application gets stuck and takes a long time to load up with no result. I guess it is because the data is large.

Answer (score 1):

You need find and replace in excel or stingr::str_replace in r.

For info on how to do it in r, with examples aplenty, check out the page on the tidyverse site: https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_replace.html

Comment: Thanks, Dom I received this error when I tried the first example on the website  
 (Error in str_replace(fruits, "[aeiou]", "-") : 
  could not find function "str_replace") do I need to install some library to use this function?

Comment: Yes. You need to type install.packages('stringr') into your console.

Comment: Also, if you want to learn r or excel please check out sites like datacamp.com